# yii2 убрать id из ссылки

Tags: php, yii2

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            '' => '',
            '/admin' => '/admin/products/create',
            '/<cat:\S+>/<name:\S+>_<id:\d+>' => '/site/product',//роут товара
            '/<cat:\S+>_<cat_id:\d+>' => '/site/cats',//роут категории
            '/<cat:\S+>/<name:\S+>_<id:\d+>' => '/site/product',//новый роут товара
            '/<cat:\S+>_<cat_id:\d+>' => '/site/cats',//новый роут категории
            '/products/<name:\S+>_<id:\d+>' => '/site/product',
            '/videos/<url:\S+>' => '/site/video',
            '/articles/<url:\S+>' => '/site/video',
            '<module:\S+>/<controller:\S+>/<action:\S+>' => '/<module>/<controller>/<action>',
            '<module:\S+>/<controller:\S+>' => '/<module>/<controller>',
            '<action:\S+>' => '/site/<action>'

        ]
```

как убрать id из ссылок, подскажите как и где поправить

Comment: если просто удалить _<id:\d+> пишет ошибку, "отсутствует обязательный параметр id"

Answer (score 0):

Если не нужны id в ссылках, нужно делать так(на примере одного роута):

В конфиге urlManager'a:

```
'products/<cat:[\w\-]+>/<alias:[\w\-]+>' => '/site/product', //роут товара
```

В контроллере `SiteController`:

```
public function actionProduct($cat, $alias)
{
    $product = Product::find()->where(['alias' => $alias])->limit(1)->one();
}
```

Тогда ссылка на товар будет иметь вид `/products/my-super-category/my-super-tovar`.

В базе в таблице `products` столбец `alias` должен быть уникальным.